# Is "worth it" used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> She marveled at snowy cherry blossoms, simultaneously seeing herself
>   as not worth it of them.

I often confuse worth, worthwhile, and worth it. Is *worth it* the right option in this case?

Comment: None of your suggestions would be valid. It's a fairly odd thing to say, but *She saw herself as **not worthy** of them* (or *...as **unworthy** of them*).

Comment: Also, "simultaneously" implies there are two ongoing actions.  I understand that the first action is meant to be her *marveling* at them, but you should put simultaneously *before* the first action.  Otherwise you can use something like "at the same time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FumbleFingers says, what you want is *not worthy* or *unworthy*.

> . . . seeing herself as unworthy of them.

To clarify the difference between these four terms:

- *X is worth Y* means that *Y*, the cost of obtaining *X*, **is an appropriate amount**—paying Y for X is a good deal. The idiom may be used with *Y* replaced by a noun or gerund expressing the money or action you must pay to get *X*

  > X is worth $100.
  >   X is worth the effort.
  >   X is worth trying harder.
- *X is worthwhile* is essentially the same idiom—it's a reduced form of *worth the while*, meaning "worth the time you have to spend".
- *X is worth it* is the same idiom, with *it* referring to a previously mentioned cost or action expended.
- But *It is worth it/Y to VERB . . .* is an *it*-cleft sentence, in which the first *it* stands for the infinitival clause *to VERB . . . * at the end—and that infinitival expresses the *X* you get by expending the cost *it/Y* in money or time or effort.

  > It's worth the cost to get this matter settled *= Getting this matter settled is worth the cost [which we will have to spend].*
- *Worthy [of X]*, however, is quite different: it expresses *deserving to receive X*. Presumably you've already 'expended' whatever *Y* entitles you to receive *X*.

  > She is worthy of our respect = *She deserves our respect.*

Comment: Often, "worth" or "worthwhile" indicates not only a cost, but the fact that paying the cost makes sense. In other words, it's a good deal.

Comment: @Alan Quite right, I need to include that.